# Signed right shift: which compiler use logical shift

Tags: c++, c, bit-shift, implementation-defined-behavior

I tested right shift with Visual Studio, Ubuntu's GCC, Intel compiler, MinGW. All shift in the sign bit. I guess Xcode's GCC does the same.

I know that the behavior is implementation specific, but it looks like that all major desktop/server compilers implement arithmetic shift. Are there any widely used compiler that doesn't shift in the sign bit?

Thank you.

Comment: Implementation defined behaviour is exactly that - defined by the implementation. Bit shifts are for treating the value as a collection of bits. Signed numbers are not meant to be treated as a collection of bits. Use an unsigned value. Or if you want to divide by two, then divide by two - don't use a shift. If and when that optimization is valid, the compiler will do it for you. See also https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT13-CPP.+Use+bitwise+operators+only+on+unsigned+operands

Comment: Wait, so you're saying right-shifting an unsigned value in C++ is undefined by the standard?! Didn't know that...

Comment: The problem is that a divide by 2 has different behavior that an arithmetic right shift.  So if you use a divide, the compiler can't change it to a shift, and if you want the signed shift behavior, there's no easy, portable way of expressing it in C

Comment: Just to elaborate on Karl's comment, you can simply treat your signed int value as an unsigned during the shifting and get predictable behaviour... there's absolutely no reason to prefer implementation specific behaviour - even if you happen to find variations that fit your needs they might disappear with a new compiler release, compiler command line options, CPU model etc..

Comment: @Mehrdad: it's right-shifting of a *signed* value that's implementation defined... unsigned values are fine. @pic11: btw - it's not just whether the sign bit "shifts in", it's also whether the new m.s.b. is a 0 or a 1 (although of course with implementation defined behaviour some pathological case is possible where the result is none-of-the-above :-/).

Comment: You're best off not knowing and not caring.  That way, you won't be tempted to write non-portable code by accident.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C runs on a lot of different architectures.  I mean a *lot* of different architectures.  You can get C code running on an embedded DSP and on a Cray supercomputer.

Most of the "implementation-defined" parts of the C standard that people take for granted really only do break on obscure architectures.  For example, there are DSPs and Cray supercomputers where `CHAR_BIT` is something huge like 32 or 64.  So if you try out your code on an x86, and maybe if you're generous a PowerPC, ARM, or SPARC, you're not likely to run into any of the really weird cases.  And that's okay.  Most code these days will always run on a byte-oriented architecture with twos-complement integers and arithmetic shifts.  I have no doubt that any new CPU architectures in the foreseeable future will be the same.

But let's look at the two most common representations for integers: two's complement and ones' complement:

```
switch ((-1) >> 1) {
case 0:
case -0:
    puts("Hello, ones' complement world!");
    // Possibly sign-magnitude.
    break;
case -1:
    puts("Hello, two's complement world!");
    break;
default:
    puts("Hello, computer without arithmetic shift");
    break;
}
```

Don't sweat it.  Just stick to `/` when you want to divide, and `>>` when you need to shift.  Even bad compilers are good at optimizing these operations.  (And remember that `x/2 != x>>1` if `x` is negative, unless you're on a ones' complement machine, which is almost certainly not true.)

The standard does guarantee that if `(int) x` is not negative, then `(int) x >> n == (unsigned) x >> n`, so there is not a lot of room for a compiler to do something completely unexpected.

Comment: I tried your code. All compiler I run it had arithmetic shift implemented.

Comment: @pic11: Changing your compiler won't do anything, which is exactly the point I'm making.  You need to change to a one's complement architecture to see the difference.

Comment: A DeathStation 9000 compiler is free to use `shr` instead of `sar` on x86 if it wants to.  The C standard just says it's "implementation defined", not that 2's complement systems have to use arithmetic shifts.  (Similar to your point about sane CPUs, much C assumes sane / helpful implementation choices.  Merely being standards compliant is *not* sufficient for a C compiler to be usable for much of anything in real life.  Sometimes writing perfectly portable code is not worth the trouble or the bloat it would cause, because ISO C is too portable in some ways.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally it depends more on the target architecture that the compiler used.  If the arch has both arithmetic (signed) and logical (unsigned) shift instructions, then C compilers for that arch will use whichever is appropriate.  On the other hand, if it has only logical shifts, the C compiler will just use that, even though it doesn't 'do the right thing' for negative values, as the C spec allows the compiler to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Cray C compiler does logical right shift on signed values by default, but there's an option to do arithmetic shift instead.

Generally, it's safe to assume that signed right shift is arithmetic.

Comment: it'll be better if you have some citation regarding the shift behavior

Answer (score -3):

As far as I can tell, the >> operator does arithmetic shift. There is however a difference between how the shift is performed for signed and unsigned integers - signed will extend the MSB (which usually is a sign bit) and unsigned will not (they are always non-negative so sign bit is always zero).

**EDIT:** apply "usually" to everything I wrote above ;).

Comment: The C standard says literally: "*If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.*". So you better check how it works on all of your target architectures (but yeah the chances are you're OK).